# What is the difference between $with and $joinWith in Yii2 and when to use them?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In the API documentation it is specified that

> - `$joinWith` - A list of relations that this query should be **joined** with
> - `$with` - A list of relations that this query should be **performed** with

What is the difference between these ActiveQuery property and under what situation should we use `$joinWith` and `$with`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Difference between `with` and `joinWith`

Using `with` method results the following SQL queries

```
$users = User::find()->with('userGroup');

SELECT * FROM `user`;
SELECT * FROM `userGroup` WHERE userId = ...
```

... while using `joinWith`will result in this SQL query

```
$users = User::find()->joinWith('userGroup', true)

SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN `userGroup` userGroup ON user.`id` = userGroup.`userId`;
```

So I'am using `joinWith` when I need to filter or search data in the related tables.

#### Additional informations

The [docu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations) -> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations will tell you this:

"*When working with relational databases, a common task is to join multiple tables and apply various query conditions and parameters to the JOIN SQL statement. Instead of calling yii\db\ActiveQuery::join() explicitly to build up the JOIN query, you may reuse the existing relation definitions and call yii\db\ActiveQuery::joinWith() to achieve this goal.*"

Which means, you are able to handle `joins`, `innerJoins`, `outerJoins` and all the good related stuff in Yii2 by yourself now. **Yii (not Yii2) only uses `join` instead without letting the user decide about type of join**. Details about "Join's" -> its a SQL-Based thing. You can read about this here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: `joinWith` still results in 2 queries... for reasons I don't quite understand... I have always understood "the fewer SQL queries the better". `joinWith` is therefore only useful if you are querying on a column in the related table, otherwise it's only a drawback.

Comment: It's not necessary true that fewer SQL queries is always better. It depends on how well are indexed columns. The greatest difference between `with` and `joinWith` would be notable on huge datasets - e.g. joining millions of records between two tables is much more intensive operation that making simple subquery on indexed column (actually two simple queries). Thus using simpler `with` in such a case would be most likely a better choice.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder try to set eagerLoading to false. this must make it perform only one query instead of two.

Answer (score 40):

`joinWith` uses `JOIN` to include the relations in the original query while `with` does not.

To illustrate further, consider a class `Post` with a relation `comments` as follows:

```
class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    ...
    public function getComments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Using `with` the code below:

```
$post = Post::find()->with('comments');
```

results in the following sql queries:

```
SELECT `post`.* FROM `post`;
SELECT `comment`.* FROM `comment` WHERE post_id IN (...)
```

Whereas the `joinWith` code below:

```
$post = Post::find()->joinWith('comments', true)
```

results in the queries:

```
SELECT `post`.* FROM post LEFT JOIN `comment` comments ON post.`id` = comments.`post_id`;
SELECT `comment`.* FROM `comment` WHERE post_id IN (...);
```

As a result, when using `joinWith` you may order by/filter/group by the relation. You may have to disambiguate the column names yourself.

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading

Answer (score 2):

Please note that in addition to above awesome answers that helped me figure out how to use `joinWith()`, that whenever you want to use `joinWith()` and you have ambiguous column names, Yii / ActiveRecord automagically seems to pick a random column, instead of what you're usually expecting (the leftmost table). It is best to specify the leftmost table in the `SELECT` clause, by specifying something like `$query->select("post.*")`. I was getting ids from some inner tables and they were getting used like they *were* from the leftmost table, until I figured this out.

Another point to note is that you *can* specify an an alias for the joinwith relation, so you could say something like:

```
$post->find()
->joinWith(["user u"])
->where(["u.id"=>$requestedUser->id])
->select("post.*")
->orderBy(["u.created_at"=>SORT_DESC]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**joinWith**

Yii2 code:

```php
$query = MiniAppRisk::find()->joinWith(['country','text','riskType'])->orderBy(['risk_publish_date' => SORT_DESC]);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
                'page' =>0
            ],
        ]);
```

result `sql1`:

```sql
SELECT `fmm_text_risk_t`.risk_id FROM `fmm_text_risk_t` 
LEFT JOIN `fmm_text_risk_target_t` ON `fmm_text_risk_t`.`risk_id` = `fmm_text_risk_target_t`.`risk_id` 
LEFT JOIN `country` ON `fmm_text_risk_target_t`.`country_id` = `country`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `fmm_text_t` ON `fmm_text_risk_t`.`text_id` = `fmm_text_t`.`text_id` 
LEFT JOIN `fmm_text_risk_type_relation_t` ON `fmm_text_risk_t`.`risk_id` = `fmm_text_risk_type_relation_t`.`risk_id` 
ORDER BY `risk_publish_date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

**with**

Yii2 code:

```php
$query = MiniAppRisk::find()->with(['country','text','riskType'])->orderBy(['risk_publish_date' => SORT_DESC]);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
                'page' =>0
            ],
        ]);
```

result `sql2`

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `fmm_text_risk_t` ORDER BY `risk_publish_date` DESC LIMIT 10 ;
SELECT * FROM `fmm_text_risk_target_t` WHERE `risk_id` IN (5563, 5562, 5561, 5560, 5559, 5558, 5557, 5556, 5555, 5554);
SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE `id` IN (7, 165, 1, 20);
SELECT * FROM `fmm_text_t` WHERE `text_id` IN (15272, 15271, 15270, 15269, 15268, 15267, 15266, 15265, 15264, 15263);
SELECT * FROM `fmm_text_risk_type_relation_t` WHERE `risk_id` IN (5563, 5562, 5561, 5560, 5559, 5558, 5557, 5556, 5555, 5554);
...more
```

It seems that the SQL generated by joinWith is less, and the efficiency is higher. However, be cautious when using joinWith for pagination. When you examine their execution results, you will notice that the number of entries per page is less than 10. This is due to the mechanism of the left join. In the case of a one-to-many relationship, it may result in data duplication, and the 'LIMIT 10' applies to the entire SQL limit, exacerbating the issue.So got these 'risk_id':

```
27680
27680
27900
27900
27900
30099
30099
30301
30301
30489
```

To address this issue, you can do the following:

```php
$query = MiniAppRisk::find()->joinWith(['country','text','riskType'])->distinct();
```

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `fmm_text_risk_t`.risk_id FROM `fmm_text_risk_t` 
LEFT JOIN `fmm_text_risk_target_t` ON `fmm_text_risk_t`.`risk_id` = `fmm_text_risk_target_t`.`risk_id` 
LEFT JOIN `country` ON `fmm_text_risk_target_t`.`country_id` = `country`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `fmm_text_t` ON `fmm_text_risk_t`.`text_id` = `fmm_text_t`.`text_id` 
LEFT JOIN `fmm_text_risk_type_relation_t` ON `fmm_text_risk_t`.`risk_id` = `fmm_text_risk_type_relation_t`.`risk_id` 
ORDER BY `risk_publish_date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

When using `with` limiting is applied only to the primary table, thus avoiding the aforementioned issue.