# Limit doesn't work well in yii2 query

Tags: yii2

I want to select 20 record in my database so I use this code to do that:

```
$query = Course::find()
                        ->alias("t")
                        ->select([
                            't.id', 't.subtitle', 't.title',
                            't.info', 't.skill_level_id', 't.special',
                            't.created', 't.modified', 't.price',
                            't.training_type_id', 't.media_id', 't.instructor_id',
                            't.extension_type'
                        ])
                        ->where(["t.deleted" => 0])
                        ->joinWith([
                            'skillLevel', "courseTarget", "requirement", 'categoryCourses', "media",
                            "instructor", "trainingType"
                        ]);
        $query->limit(20);
        return $query->all();
```

but this code will select just 5 records,

When I remove the `joinWith` part, my code works fine and select 20 records.
Modified code:

```
   $query = Course::find()
                    ->alias("t")
                    ->select([
                        't.id', 't.subtitle', 't.title',
                        't.info', 't.skill_level_id', 't.special',
                        't.created', 't.modified', 't.price',
                        't.training_type_id', 't.media_id', 't.instructor_id',
                        't.extension_type'
                    ])
                    ->where(["t.deleted" => 0]);
    $query->limit(20);
    return $query->all();
```

The modified code will return 20 records.

UPDATE1:

When I remove the `limit(20)` it will return `496` records but when I added `limit(20)` It just returns 5.

```
$query = Course::find()
                        ->alias("t")
                        ->select([
                            't.id', 't.subtitle', 't.title',
                            't.info', 't.skill_level_id', 't.special',
                            't.created', 't.modified', 't.price',
                            't.training_type_id', 't.media_id', 't.instructor_id',
                            't.extension_type'
                        ])
                        ->where(["t.deleted" => 0])
                        ->joinWith([
                            'skillLevel', "courseTarget", "requirement", 'categoryCourses', "media",
                            "instructor", "trainingType"
                        ]);
        return $query->all()
```

This code works fine and returns everything but the `limit()` query will made the response wrong

Comment: could be that the joined  query have only 5 rows

Comment: what happens if you remove the `select` part and select everything i recon it will show you correct number of records?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `Course` have `hasMany` relation with multiple items. So if you have `Course` with 2 `requirement`s, such query will return 2 rows with duplicated `Course` data for each `requirement`. Duplicated data is merged into one `Course` model, so 2 rows becomes one model. This is exactly what is happened here - query returns 20 rows, but it has only 5 unique `Course` models.

If you don't need to access relations in SQL query (for example for filtering), you can replace [`joinWith()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail) with [`with()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#with()-detail) - it will not perform `JOIN` on SQL query, only register eager loading for relations. You can read more about differences between these two methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600048/what-is-the-difference-between-with-and-joinwith-in-yii2-and-when-to-use-them).

If you need this `JOIN` you should probably group results by `Course` ID, to avoid duplicated `Course` rows.

```
$query->groupBy('t.id');
```